# Monitor bandwidth consumed by Push/Target Stream in Wowza

Tags: wowza, java

I am using Wowza Steaming Engine 4.4.1. I am developing module for user to show bandwidth consumption. I am following this link https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?182-How-to-get-detailed-server-info-with-an-HTTP-Provider 
Following this link able to get RTMP, RTP and HTTP bandwidth consumption. But also want to get bandwidth consumed by Push/Target stream. But bandwidth consumption about push stream not mention in above link. Any suggestion

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the IOPerformanceCounter class and get the information from the getMessagesOutBytes method. You can also view this by using the JConsole IOPerformance object, in the messagesOutBytes attribute. This is a cumulative value though, and includes all outbound connections, not just stream target connections.